# get_query_vars always retruns empty value

Tags: php

I try to get this example running:

```
function themeslug_query_vars( $qvars ) {   
    $qvars[] = 'custom_query_var';
    return $qvars; 
} 

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'themeslug_query_vars' );

$testvar = get_query_var('custom_query_var'); 

echo "testvar=[$testvar]";
```

as found on page https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

With my test page I can see my little testvar string but with "?custom_query_var=help" at the end of my URL my "testvar" is empty.

In my test scenario I use the original twentytwentyone theme with no plugins activated. My code is placed at the end of functions.php.

Does anybody have me an advice of how to fix this issue?

Regards
Peti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my test scenario I use the original twentytwentyone theme with no
> plugins activated. **My code is placed at the end of functions.php.**

This is the problem. Your code is running as soon as functions.php is loaded, which is before the query vars are populated. If you use `get_query_var()` inside an action hook that runs later, or inside a block or shortcode, it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for taking some time to solve my problem. And when I implement your recommendation everything works fine as expected :-) Regards,
Peti